# Re-printing a div without having to refresh the page (incursion?)

Tags: javascript, html, function

I've been stuck with this for a while and have tried a few different things to no avail.

I have a function that prints elements to a page. Within that function, I have an addEventListener that upon click will change the order of those elements. When I refresh the page, it works, and the order is changed. However, I'd actually like the order to be changed upon click.

My original thought it calling the function within itself which I've tried but that doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts here?

```
printElements()
{
     //prints elements to the page
     addEventListener('click', function(event)
     {
        //changes order of elements
        div.innerHTML = ''
        printElements()
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to share the whole function.

Answer (score 0):

First get the info of the elements in array or object
Second remove all the elements
Third create the elements and set the info that you stored to them
Last append the the elements in

## ***order***

that you want